# How to use stripchart() in R?

Tags: r, plot, stripchart

I have problems to use `stripchart()` with the right placement of X- and Y-axes and with the *correct direction* of the stacked points.

This MWE imitates the steps I do with my real data

```
# stratify mtcars$mpg_strat
mtcars$mpg_strat <- cut(mtcars$mpg, breaks=seq(0,50,by=5))

stripchart(gear~mpg_strat,
           data=mtcars,
           method="stack",
           offset=.5, pch=20)
```

[image]

- I want to have `gear` in the Y-axis and `mpg_strat` (stratified `mpg`) on the X-axis.
- And the points should be stacked from bottom to top (vertical) and not from left to right (horizontal).

The example here doesn't produce it that way. When I try to switch `mpg_strat~gear` I get an error

```
Fehler in Summary.factor(c(5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L,  : 
‘range’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: Your formula needs to be in the form `numeric ~ grouping_factor` - so `as.numeric(mpg_strat) ~ gear` I think will work. And the numeric conversion should ultimately be done back when you do the `cut()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
stripchart(as.numeric(mpg_strat) ~ gear,
       data=mtcars,
       method="stack",
    xaxt = "n", 
    xlab="mpg_strat",
    ylab="gear",
       offset=.5, pch=20)
axis(1, at=3:7, labels=levels(mtcars$mpg_strat)[3:7])
```

[image]